# Is it better to always instantiate a fragment or keep a reference to it?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating an app that uses a number of fragments, inside a ViewPager.

Up to now I always fed the ViewPager a new instance of each fragment it needed , because all the examples on google developers seem to say that , that is the correct thing to do.

Those fragments used their parent Activity to retrieve their state/data and update themselves in OnCreateView.

One of the new fragments is a NewsFragment which contains either a NewsHeadersFragment or a NewsArticleFragment, and those two need to communicate.

What I do is send the message article_clicked(article) from NewsHeaderFragment to my Activity (unfortunatelly I haven't found a way to communicate with the parent fragment) and the Activity sends a message to the NewsFragment to change its child fragment

In order to do this it seems I must keep a reference to the NewsFragment, so I was thinking that maybe I should not always create a new instance of fragments.

My question is, is it better to always create a new instance of the NewsFragment and just update the reference, or only create an instance when the reference is null and always return the reference.

i.e. is this better:

```
private static NewsFragment _news;
public static NewsFragment get_news_fragment() {
    _news = NewsFragment.NewInstance();
    return _news;
}
```

or this?

```
private static NewsFragment _news;
public static NewsFragment get_news_fragment() {
    if (_news == null) _news = NewsFragment.NewInstance();
    return _news;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1):

I recommend always creating fragments when needed (as done in google developers samples) for one important reason which is to prevent potential `OutOfMemoryException`s. Keeping hard references to a Fragment/Activity  outside its lifecycle makes it illegible for garbage collection and pave way for the infamous OOMs.

For your scenario I would recommend you to try some sort of EventBus (pub / sub mechanism) to communicate from your activity to fragment.

Comment: But since I keep a static reference to the fragments, doesn't that mean that even when they do not exist in the fragment manager, when the ViewPager tries to show them again it will always show the same fragment? so in effect  one scenario (with the new instances) means that fragments are created and destroyed all the time, the other (with the references) means that they are created once and stay forever. Isn't that better memorywise?

Comment: You do make a valid point. However, when `onDestroyed()` is called in a fragment, the android system expects the GC to sweep the fragment in the next run. So it is highly not recommended to to interrupt this behaviour by holding a static reference to a fragment whose lifecycle is already ended (`onDestroyed()` called). You may stick with static reference but remember that android runs on wide variety of devices with different memory sizes. What may work on your device may not work on a low-end device!

Answer (score 0):

It‘s better to create a new fragment. However, it's also depends on what you want to do in them. If you do something async，or use  observer mode, keeping a reference is better

Comment: I do use async things, for example loading data from the server and then notifying the appropriate fragments that they have new data, but I can do that with callbacks at the moment without needing to keep a reference

Comment: by the way what do you mean by observer mode?

Comment: sorry， it should be Observer Pattern. What i want to say is when you need to keep a instance

Answer (score 0):

The data you want to share inside your NewsFragment you can have it in system context class and store the data there(getter/setter) , however you just require to call this class method instead of creating your fragment's instance everytime.

Comment: I actually don't have any data held in the fragments, all data at the moment is either stored in the main activity, or in the application's Application singleton

Comment: My problem is that the fragments need to work together through third parties. for example at the moment the flow is, Headers fragment sends MainActivity that the user selected an article, MainActivity notifies the NewsFragment that it should show the ArticleFragment, and when that fragment executes the OnCreateView method it asks the MainActivity for the article it should show. But since I can't find the fragments through fragmentManager (not using support libaries) I thought the only way to go is keep a reference to them